# puppeteer dynamic selector returning multiple objects

Tags: javascript, dom, automated-tests, puppeteer, e2e-testing

[image: dom tree]

This is how my DOM tree looks like. The puppeteer code that I use looks like this.

```
  const selector = '[class^="SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__"]';
  const nodes = Array.from(await page.$$(selector));
  const nodeList = Array.from(nodes).map(element => element);
```

In the DOM structure, "*SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__*" is repeated multiple times and has 3 divs nested inside it. All these elements have dynamic class names as shown in the image.

I need to obtain the values of these 3 divs (as image shows in the first block - HEADING, DESCRIPTION)

With the code that I tried, I get collection of elements but not sure how to obtain values of child objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.$$` resolve to an array of ElementHandle so the `Array.from` is redundant.
You can use `children` property of the element and get the first three children's innerText like this:

```js
const values = await page.$$eval('[class^="SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__"]', elements => elements.map(el => [...el.children].filter((el, index) => index < 3).map(el => el.innerText)))
```

If you need the nodes in puppeteer context, you can use [`evaluateHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```js
const selector = '[class^="SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__"]';
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // Replace this JS code with Puppeteer's
const nodeList = Array.from(nodes).map(element => element);
const ChildNodesVal = [];
console.log(nodeList);
nodeList.forEach((e,i)=>
{
    ChildNodesVal[i] = [];
    e.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(child => ChildNodesVal[i].push(child.textContent))
});
console.log(ChildNodesVal);
```

```html
<div class="SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__">
  <div class="first1">1</div>
  <div class="first2">2</div>
  <div class="first3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="SubscriptionBilling_tierInclusion__">
  <div class="first4">4</div>
  <div class="first5">5</div>
  <div class="first6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think we can directly access document in puppeteer. Document can only be accessed inside evaluate as far as I know.

Comment: I think you already are getting `nodes` with `const nodes = Array.from(await page.$$(selector));`. I asked to replace my line of code with your puppeteer's and give it a try.

Comment: fails with e.querySelectorAll('div')